# Dynamic table in pimcore

Tags: pimcore

Can I make dynamic table with  area brick in pimcore? Something like this:

[image: this]

with possibility to change the rotation angle.

Can I change style, add class to tbody tag, or set table header in pimcore editables - table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CKEditor and css's styling "transform: rotate(45deg)".